# Why doesn't time.sleep work as with print end arguments?

Tags: python, time, printing

I am trying to use time.sleep() to pause in between print statements.

```
import time
def test():
    print("something", end="")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" and ", end="")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("something")
```

When I use the end argument, the code waits before it starts to print. It should print, wait, print, wait, and print ("something, wait, and, wait, something"). However, when I use the end argument, it waits, and prints "wait something and something". This code works as I wanted it to without the end argumets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output device is line-buffered and only flushes when a new line is output. Add `flush=True` as an additional parameter to `print` to force a flush to the output.